# Pass multiple rows to function using spark UDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have this code that makes use of a udf to make an HTTP request:

```
def insert(name, insertURL):
    
    url = insertURL

    try: 
        payload = json.dumps({
                    "records": [
                        {
                            "fields": {
                                "name": name
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                })

        headers = {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                }
        response = requests.request(
                    "POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload) 
        dataRes = response.json()
        return dataRes
    
    except Exception as e
        print("Error Occurred:", e)

def insertUDF(insertURL):
    return udf(lambda z: insert(z, insertURL), StringType()) 

def main():

    match args.subparser:

        case 'Insert':
            fake = Faker()

            columns = ["serial", "name"]
            data = []
            for i in range(10):
                data.append((i,fake.name()))

            df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=columns)
            df.show(truncate=False)
            
            df.withColumn("Name", insertUDF(args.insertURL)(col("name"))).show()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

I would like to change the `payload` such that it takes multiple fields for performance such that the payload becomes:

```
payload = json.dumps({
                    "records": [
                        {
                            "fields": {
                                "name": name
                            },
                             "fields": {
                                "name": name
                            },
                             "fields": {
                                "name": name
                            },
                             "fields": {
                                "name": name
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                })
```

where the `name` in the `fields` takes the first name present in the dataframe, then second, then third and so on in the same payload, for example if the dataframe is:

```
serial|name               |
+-----+-------------------+
|0    |Christina Bishop   |
|1    |Vincent Smith      |
|2    |Deanna Brown       |
|3    |James Medina MD    |
|4    |Ashley Harper      |
|5    |Tina Schultz       |
|6    |Patrick Archer     |
|7    |Mark Campbell      |
|8    |Anthony Roach      |
|9    |Justin Jackson     |
```

then in the first payload names till `James` have been included.

How do I do this?

Comment: is there any way you can partition your data into chunks before the dataframe is created? because if you could, then having another column called `batch` containing a unique key for the rows to be processed would help improve performance and I think would also integrate with what you have so far

Comment: Hi, how would partitioning the data into chunks help increase the number of names (rows) being sent in the same http payload?

Comment: because then you could perform an operation where you collect the contents of an entire field from each chunk. in the udf you have right now, you would need to specify how many rows to extract if i'm not mistaken

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pass multiple rows into a UDF, you can only groupby and collect_list or collect_set to achieve similar.  That said, given your use case, you would be better served using foreachPartition and grouping yourself.